# Do I need to modify timeout on spurious wakeups when using Object.wait( int timeout)?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

[The Javadoc for `Object.wait( timeout )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) recommends calling `wait` in a loop which checks the predicate in order to handle spurious wakeups:

```
while ( !predicate )
    Object.wait( timeout )
```

This example however doesn't take into account that in the event of a spurious wakeup, timeout would need to be modified on subsequent loop iterations to account for time waited.  Pthreads avoids this problem by specifying an absolute time for the timeout.  Do I need to handle this myself or is timeout decremented internally?